# Using pydantic to change int to string

Tags: python, pydantic

I am sometimes getting data that is either a string or int for 2 of my values. Im trying to figure out the best solution for handling this and I am using pydantic v2. Ive been studying the @field_validtaors(pre=True) but haven't been successful.

Here's my code:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    system_id: str
    db_id: str
    id: str
    record: dict
    isValid: bool

  @field_validator("id", mode='before')            <<<--------- not working
    def transform_system_id_to_str(cls, value) -> str:
        return str(value)
    
  @field_validator("system_id", mode='before')     <<<--------- not working
    def transform_system_id_to_str(cls, value: str | int) -> str:
        if isinstance(value, str):
            print('yes')
            return value
        return str(value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can validate more than one fields in a `field_validator`.

Try the following code:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    system_id: str
    db_id: str
    id: str
    record: dict
    isValid: bool

    @field_validator("id","system_id", mode='before')

    def transform_id_to_str(cls, value) -> str:
        return str(value)

u = User(system_id='199', db_id="1", id='99', record={}, isValid=True)
print(u)  ## system_id='199' db_id='1' id='99' record={} isValid=True

u = User(system_id=199, db_id="1", id=99, record={}, isValid=True)
print(u)  ## system_id='199' db_id='1' id='99' record={} isValid=True
```

> Before validators run before Pydantic's internal parsing and
> validation (e.g. coercion of a str to an int).
> https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/

Answer (score 3):

From docs you can use type coercion, [coerce number to str](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/config/#pydantic.config.ConfigDict.coerce_numbers_to_str)

```py
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(coerce_numbers_to_str=True)
        
    int_field: int
    str_field: str

>>> MyModel(int_field=1, str_field=2)
MyModel(int_field=1, str_field='2')
>>> MyModel(int_field=1, str_field='2')
MyModel(int_field=1, str_field='2')
>>> MyModel(int_field=1, str_field=2.3)
MyModel(int_field=1, str_field='2.3')
```

Answer (score 1):

## Fixing your code

The code doesn't work because you used the same name for both validators. Rename one of them and everything will work just fine (provided you fix indentation issues from the original post too).

Some comments on the code:

- both functions transform ANY value to `str`, not only `int`. This means that even `None` will be transformed to `"None"`. I'm not sure this is expected behavior
- As [Kostas Nitaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18671446/kostas-nitaf) mentioned, you could apply the same function to both fields since they do the same thing.

## Alternative solution

As an alternative I suggest using `pydantic.BeforeValidator`. Amongst other things it allows to define new field annotations with validators wrapped in them.

```py
from typing import Annotated, Any
from pydantic import BaseModel, BeforeValidator

# define validator function
def coerce_int_to_str(data: Any) -> Any:
    """Transform input int to str, return other types as is"""
    if isinstance(data, int): #Int can be replaced with any type(s) to coerce
        return str(data)
    return data 

# Define the annotation. coerce_int_to_str will be applied 
# to any input field with this annotation 

CoercedStr = Annotated[str, BeforeValidator(coerce_int_to_str)]

#And finally the pydantic model
class User(BaseModel):
    system_id: CoercedStr
    db_id: str
    id: CoercedStr
    record: dict
    isValid: bool
```

Example usage - `int` is transformed into string:

```
user = User(system_id=5,db_id="dummy_id", id=5, record={}, isValid=False)
print(user)
# User(system_id='5', db_id='dummy_id', id='5', record={}, isValid=False)
print(type(user.system_id))
# <class 'str'>
```

While a `float` throws a validation error as expected:

```
another_user = User(system_id=5.0,db_id="dummy_id", id=5, record={}, isValid=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 164, in __init__
    __pydantic_self__.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=__pydantic_self__)
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for User
system_id
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=5.0, input_type=float]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/string_type
```

**Pros** of this approach:

- The new annotation isn't bound to defined `User` class
- You don't need to define separate `field_validator`s each time you use this functionality - annotated fields are reusable

**Cons** I can think of:

- Usage of a bit advanced stuff like `Annotated` and `BeforeValidator`, which might be hard to understand for beginners.

References:

- [Pydantic Validators Documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/#before-after-wrap-and-plain-validators)